# Problem Using Pivot_Table in Python: is there any way to keep the original order of the data and not having multiindex?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I am trying to recreate my data frame. Below is the original dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['January','Monday',0,1,20],['January','Monday',1,2,15],['January','Wednesday',0,1,35],['March','Monday',0,1,23],['March','Monday',1,2,50],['March','Monday',2,3,60] ,['April','Wednesday',0,1,75]],columns = ['Month','Day','Data1','Data2','Random'])

     Month        Day  Data1  Data2  Random
0  January     Monday      0      1      20
1  January     Monday      1      2      15
2  January  Wednesday      0      1      35
3    March     Monday      0      1      23
4    March     Monday      1      2      50
5    March     Monday      2      3      60
6    April  Wednesday      0      1      75
```

I am aiming to achieve the below result:

```
     Month        Day  0    1    2
0  January     Monday  1  2.0  NaN
1  January     Monday  1  2.0  NaN
2  January  Wednesday  1  NaN  NaN
3    March     Monday  1  2.0  3.0
```

I tried to use the pivot_table as below, but of course it did not work as pivot_table does not allow any duplicate for the index and I will also have multiindex which causes problems in my later process.

```
df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, values = 'Data2', index = ['Month','Day'], columns = ['Data1'])

Data1                0    1    2
Month   Day                     
April   Wednesday  1.0  NaN  NaN
January Monday     1.0  2.0  NaN
        Wednesday  1.0  NaN  NaN
March   Monday     1.0  2.0  3.0
```

Is there any other way to get my aimed result? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Row 0 and 1 is the same in your desired result. Can you try to elaborate.

Comment: Exactly, row 0 and 1 is indeed the same. If I use pivot_table, there will be no duplicate. Basically, I want the data to be classified based on Month and Day. The new data frame will have new columns that are based on the value from column Data1 of the original data frame. For example for month January and day Monday, its Data1 is 0 and 1 while Data2 is 1 and 2, the new data frame will still show 2 rows of Month January and day Monday (like the original data frame), and in each row the column 0 is filled with 1 and column 1 is filled by 2. I hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using groupby with unstack:

```
df.groupby(['Month','Day','Data2'])['Data2'].first().unstack().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
Data2    Month        Day    1    2    3
0        April  Wednesday  1.0  NaN  NaN
1      January     Monday  1.0  2.0  NaN
2      January  Wednesday  1.0  NaN  NaN
3        March     Monday  1.0  2.0  3.0
```